# python conditional list creation from 2D lists

Tags: python, list

Say I've got a list of lists. Say the inner list of three elements in size and looks like this:

```
['apple', 'fruit', 1.23]
```

The outer list looks like this

```
data = [['apple', 'fruit', 1.23],
        ['pear', 'fruit', 2.34],
        ['lettuce', 'vegetable', 3.45]]
```

I want to iterate through the outer list and cull data for a temporary list only in the case that element 1 matches some keyword (aka: 'fruit'). So, if I'm matching fruit, I would end up with this:

```
tempList = [('apple', 1.23), ('pear', 2.34)]
```

This is one way to accomplish this:

```
tempList = []
for i in data:
   if i[1] == 'fruit':
      tempList.append(i[0], i[2])
```

is there some 'Pythonic' way to do this in fewer lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions, using tuple indexing or slicing

```
tempList = [(i[0], i[2]) for i in data if i[1] == 'fruit']
tempList = [i[:1]+i[2:] for i in data if i[1] == 'fruit']
```

Also, generator expressions if you don't need a list, just the sequence.
(here with tuple unpacking)

```
>>> tempListGen = ((a,c) for a,b,c in data if b == 'fruit')
>>> tempListGen
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0266FD50>
>>> print sorted(tempListGen)
[('apple', 1.23), ('pear', 2.34)]
```

(tested with Python 2.7)

Comment: even though this wasn't stated in my question (in the interest of brevity), my inner list is fairly lengthy so using indicees (i[x]) instead of a full unpack is beneficial

Comment: @dls: Consider slicing i[:1]+i[2:] to make a copy that removes one element. (Now with correct syntax, thanks 6502!)

Answer (score 5):

```
[(i, k) for i, j, k in data if j == 'fruit']
```

Answer (score 3):

Tuple assignment could make the code easier to understand, paired with a list comprehension for compactness:

```
tempList = [(item, price) for item, kind, price in data if kind == 'fruit']
```

Answer (score 1):

The List Comprehension!

```
tempList = [(i[0], i[2]) for i in data if i[1] == 'fruit']
```

Will give the same result in fewer lines and will probably execute faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[x[0], x[2]] for x in data if x[1] == 'fruit']
```